# Remove Linux directories containing ONLY old files

Tags: files, recursive

We have numerous directories that each contain 2 files, one of which is a hidden file.  We want to remove all those directories and their contents that contain ONLY files that have a modification date older than 180 days.  So, for example, if we have the following:

```
Dir1   Jan 1 2000
     File1A   Jan 1 2000
     File1B   Jan 1 2000
Dir2   Jan 1 2000
     File2A   Jan 1 2014
     File2B   Jan 1 2014
Dir3   Jan 1 2000
     File3A   Jan 1 2014
     File3B   Jan 1 2000
```

I need a Linux command that will remove only Dir1 and all of its contents including the hidden file.  Dir2 and Dir 3 would remain untouched because each contain at least one file that is newer than 180 days ago.

I've played around with listing those directories that contain a newer file but I couldn't find an "inverse" command that would then remove all the "other" directories.

Answer (score 6):

With GNU tools:

```
for d in Dir*; do
  find "$d" -mindepth 1 -mtime -180 -print -quit | grep -q . ||
    echo rm -rf "$d"
done
```

Remove the `echo` when satisfied. Remove the `-q` to find out why a directory is not being removed.

Comment: Stephane, `-mtime -180` does not indicate 180 days and older. It is rather from now to 180 days if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks Stephane - but your answer also doesn't address the most critical component which is that I only want to remove directories that contain ONLY old (180+ days) files

Comment: @val0x00ff It removes the directories that do not contain files younger than 180 days.

Comment: @pk7, if the directories contain only 180+ days (or if the directories are empty), then `find` will output nothing, then `grep` will return false, then `echo rm` will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

One of the approaches is:

```
while read -r line; do rm -rf "${line%%/*}"; done < <(find . -type f -mtime +180 -printf "%P\n")
```

Pipe the into `read` and execute a command accordingly.

Comment: Thanks val0x00ff- but your answer doesn't address the most critical component which is that I only want to remove directories that contain ONLY old (180+ days) files